# ComboBox value is not updated on a event wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I am creating a ComboBox as:

```
combo= ['a', 'b', 'c']
self.stm_checkpoint_drop=wx.ComboBox(self.panel, -1, value='Options', choices=combo)
self.stm_checkpoint_drop.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.oncombo)

def oncombo(self,event):
    selected = self.stm_checkpoint_drop.GetValue()
```

Variable selected remains the default value 'Options'. How do I get the value selected from the combo list stored in variable selected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why your code isn't working, there does not seem to be an obvious error. Check if this works and check against your code.

```
import wx

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.my_choices = ["Option A","Option B","Option C"]
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.cbx = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, -1, value="Choose an Option", pos=(10,30), size=(300,30),choices=self.my_choices)
        self.cbx.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_selection)
        self.txt1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "Selected Value", pos=(10,100), size=(300,30))
        self.txt2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "Selected Selection", pos=(10,130), size=(300,30))
        self.txt3 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "Selected String", pos=(10,160), size=(300,30))

    def on_selection(self, evt):
        Choice = self.cbx.GetValue()
        self.txt1.SetValue(Choice)
        Choice = self.cbx.GetSelection()
        self.txt2.SetValue(str(Choice))
        Choice = self.cbx.GetStringSelection()
        self.txt3.SetValue(Choice)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = wx.App()
    Myframe().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```